# html タグに関するシノニムの提案

Tags: 討議, 完了, タグ, タグの別名の提案

### 提案内容

[html](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) のタグシノニムとして、[html5](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) を提案します。

---

### 提案理由

HTML5 で導入された機能は一般的になったため、もはや HTML を特定バージョンによって区別する意味はなくなりつつあると思います。

また、W3C 勧告には WHATWG HTML, DOM のレビュードラフトが採用される<sup>[[1]](https://www.w3.org/blog/2019/05/w3c-and-whatwg-to-work-together-to-advance-the-open-web-platform/)</sup>ため、今後 HTML5 といった使い分けがかえって混乱を招く場合も考えられます。

> ## W3C and WHATWG to work together to advance the open Web platform<sup>[[1]](https://www.w3.org/blog/2019/05/w3c-and-whatwg-to-work-together-to-advance-the-open-web-platform/)</sup>
>
> Motivated by the belief that having two distinct HTML and DOM specifications claiming to be normative is generally harmful for the community, and the mutual desire to bring the work back together, W3C and WHATWG agree to the following terms:
>
> - W3C and WHATWG work together on HTML and DOM, in the WHATWG repositories, to produce a Living Standard and Recommendation/Review Draft-snapshots
> - WHATWG maintains the HTML and DOM Living Standards
> - W3C facilitates community work directly in the WHATWG repositories (bridging communities, developing use cases, filing issues, writing tests, mediating issue resolution)
> - W3C stops independent publishing of a designated list of specifications related to HTML and DOM and instead will work to take WHATWG Review Drafts to W3C Recommendations

Comment: 英語版Stack Overflowでは2019年5月に[同様の提案がなされ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385027/5989200)、現在「別名化はされているが、マージはされていない」状態になっていました。別名化した上で、何か想定外の影響が無いか調べている段階です。英語版には [html5-feature] というタグも存在するのが日本語版とは違いますが、同じような議論になりそうです。

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん> 質問をマージして不要なタグを削除(？)することも出来るのは初めて知りました(であれば、マージするほうが好ましい気がします)。特に反対意見がなければ、日本語版でも、英語版に倣って暫定的にシノニム化することになるのでしょうか？

Comment: supa さん、はい。タグシノニムは取り消せますが、マージは取り消せないためです。シノニムを作っても既存のタグは消えませんが、マージすると既存のタグを付け替えることになります。たとえば今回の場合 [html5] を [html] へマージすると、以降 [html5] というタグは（簡単には）使えなくなるため、やや慎重になる必要があります。

Comment: シノニム化は迷わず賛成と言えますがマージはどうでしょうね。質問の中身までは確認していませんが、["html"のﾄｯﾌﾟﾕｰｻﾞｰ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/html/topusers)と["html5"のﾄｯﾌﾟﾕｰｻﾞｰ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/html5/topusers)を比較したところ`html5`での質問は最近ではなさそうに見えます。

Comment: [tag:html] の別名として [tag:html5] を作成することに反対が無さそうなので、対応予定といたします。
一週間程度、追加の意見を待った後に作業します。（今回はマージはしません）

Answer (score 2):

[html5](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) を [html](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) の別名にしました。マージは行なっていません。

---

なお、マージせず別名の設定のみという状態は、いわば試用期間です。この状態では、一部のAPIや検索クエリで、[html5](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) のみが付いた質問が結果から得られません。しばらく、これで様子を見た後、いずれ最終的な判断をする必要が有ります。選択肢は下記のいずれかです。

- 両者は同じと扱って問題無かった → マージ
- 両者は別の役割があり同一視できなかった → 別名を解除

（こういった「マージ待ち」のタグに関しては、いずれ他も含め意見を募集し、マージか別名の解除かを決定します）