# マージ待ちのタグ、google-cloud、html5、shellscript、es6 のマージを実行します

Tags: 機能の要求, タグ, タグの付け替えの提案

現在、[マージ待ちのタグ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?tab=Newest&filter=Merge)が4つ有ります。これらのタグをマージしたいと思います。ご意見など有ればお寄せ下さい（少なくとも一ヶ月程度は意見を待つ予定です）。

- マージすべきでは無いタグが有る、という意見が有った場合は、そのタグを今回の作業対象から外し、個別に議論します
- 作業実行前にマージ待ちのタグが増えたとしても、そのタグは今回の対象に含めません

#### マージする予定のタグ

- 「google-cloud」

  - マージ先: [google-cloud-platform](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform)
  - 別名設定時の議論: [google-cloud-platform タグを新設し、google-cloud タグを deprecate していきたい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3367/)
- 「html5」

  - マージ先: [html](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)
  - 別名設定時の議論: [html タグに関するシノニムの提案](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3040/)
- 「shellscript」

  - マージ先: [shell](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell)
  - 別名設定時の議論: [タグ [shellscript] と [shell] のマージを提案します](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3788/)
- 「es6」

  - マージ先: [ecmascript-6](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6)

---

#### マージ待ちとは

「マージ待ち（Pending merge）」とは、タグが別名として設定されているものの、ターゲットのタグにマージされていない状態です。主に検索時に不都合が生じますので、マージする必要が有ります。

#### 生じている検索時の不都合の例

マージせずにおいた場合に生じる不都合に関しては [「タグの「別名」や「マージ」はどのような機能ですか？」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3982/) などで説明されていますが、今回の対象タグにおける具体例を見ると解り易いかも知れません。

まず、[「LWFS」という語を検索](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=LWFS)してみます。

> [image: 「LSFS」の検索結果]

すると、上のように[「LWFSを利用しているとscript not usedという警告が出ることがある」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2536/) という質問が検索結果として得られます。この質問には、タグ「html5」が付与されていますから、次は[それをタグ指定として含めて検索](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=LWFS+%5Bhtml5%5D)してみます。

> [image: 「LWFS [html5]」の検索結果]

「html5」というタグ指定が「html」に置き換えられて検索されています。これは別名として設定されているからです。しかし、マージはされていないので、先ほどの質問には「html」というタグが付与されていません。結果として、今度の検索では何も得られなくなってしまっています。

マージによって、こういった問題は解消されます。